# Silent Install in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When I run the following command on a command line, I am able to silently install the package but when I put the following code in a objective c program and run it. The package does not get installed.

Shell command -

echo password | sudo -S installer -pkg /Users/prashanth/Desktop/AppTest.mpkg -target /

Objective C -

system(@"echo password | sudo -S installer -pkg /Users/prashanth/Desktop/AppTest.mpkg -target /");

Comment: NSTask, and only for sudo, would be better, since you could write the password into its stdin yourself, but still not the correct solution. Closer would be AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges  (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges). The method recommended by the documentation is to do the real work (running installer) in a setuid-root tool, and use AEWP only to set its setuid status. (Of course, that assumes your app bundle is not on a read-only volume.)

Comment: And I'm hoping that this is only for testing and you don't intend to silently install anything in a real application.

Comment: @Prashant your shell command worked perfectly for silent install. But  I want to pass argument with this shell command. And i want to get this argument inside post installation script in package installer . Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `system()` function does not take an NSString. Get rid of the `@`.

However, I don't recommend this. It pretty much defeats the point of having an administrator password. Anyone with read access to the app binary or the ability to see *just the names* of running programs will be able to see the password in plaintext.

Comment: Also, any user running, say, `ps ax` will be able to see that password.

Comment: @Bavarious - Sure, will be removing that